# Vue Router addRoute blank at router-view

Tags: vue.js, vue-router, vue-router4

First, sorry for my bad english.
I'm learning about modular architecture / Folder By Feature in vue just like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xfEWw.png)
In user module I created a router like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnwZx.png)
And add user's router to main router like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TId19.png)
Builder router is my apps routing after user logged in. And my main router is like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/720Ls.png)
What's happening is everything works fine when I access `/dashboard` or `/about` or other page that defined main router. And I click the `/user` router (it cames from user's module router) and it also work fine. But when I access `/dashboard` again. the router view show nothing (it is `<!-- -->` in dev console).

1. It's OK when access dashboard. Page displayed (white boxes)
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwL7U.png)
2. Also OK in user module router
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9P5z.png)
3. It became blank when I access `/dashboard` again
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PghHd.png)
   The structure of router-view

```
   <router-view> Page Loader
      <router-view> Module Loader (Index, Add, Edit)
```

This is my main router

```js
const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Builder',
    component: Builder,
    meta: {
      requiresAuth: true
    },
    redirect: '/dashboard',
    children: [
       {
        path: 'dashboard',
        name: 'Dashboard',
        meta: {
          pageTitle: 'Dashboard',
          requiresAuth: true
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "dashboard" */ '../views/Dashboard.vue')
      },
      {
        path: 'about',
        name: 'About',
        meta: {
          pageTitle: 'About',
          requiresAuth: true,
          breadcrumb: [
            {
              label: 'About',
              to: '/about'
            }
          ]
        },
        component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '@/views/About.vue')
      },
    ]
  };

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
})

export default router
```

2. Registering Route

```js
import router from '../router/index'
import store from '../store/index'

const registerModule = (name, module: any) => {
  if (module.store) {
    store.registerModule(name, module.store)
  }

  if (module.router) {
    module.router.forEach(item => {
      router.addRoute('Builder', item)
    })
  }
}

export const registerModules = (modules: any) => {
  Object.keys(modules).forEach(moduleKey => {
    const module = modules[moduleKey]
    registerModule(moduleKey, module)
  })
}
```

3. User Module Route

```js
const moduleRoute = [{
  path: '/user',
  name: 'User',
  component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ '../user/Module.vue'),
  meta: {
    pageTitle: 'User Management Builder',
    requiresAuth: true,
    breadcrumb: [
      {
        label: 'User',
        to: '/user'
      }
    ]
  },
  children: [
    {
      path: 'list',
      name: 'UserList',
      meta: {
        pageTitle: 'User Management',
        requiresAuth: true,
        breadcrumb: [
          {
            label: 'User',
            to: '/user'
          }
        ]
      },
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ '../user/views/Index.vue')
    },
    {
      path: 'add',
      name: 'UserAdd',
      meta: {
        pageTitle: 'User Add',
        requiresAuth: true,
        breadcrumb: [
          {
            label: 'User',
            to: '/user'
          }
        ]
      },
      component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "user" */ '@/modules/user/views/Add.vue')
    }
]
}]

export default moduleRoute
```

Extra Note:
I'm using webpack too in case it it affects my problem

Any help please. Thank you in advance.

Comment: please add your code examples as code examples, not images, especially not external ones.

Comment: @D.Schaller Done sir